# How to keep PlaybackRate throughout the lifetime of the MediaPlayerElement?

Tags: uwp, media-player

In MediaElement, there is a property called [DefaultPlaybackRate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.defaultplaybackrate#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_MediaElement_DefaultPlaybackRate), which will persist throughout the lifetime of the MediaElement.

But `MediaPlayerElement` doesn't have property `DefaultPlaybackRate`.

I have checked that the `PlaybackRate` will always be set to 1.0 when playing another video.

```
private void PlaybackSession_PlaybackRateChanged(MediaPlaybackSession sender, object args)
{
    Globals.playbackRate = mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackRate;
}
```

So is there any better way to do that?

Comment: I tested the PlaybackRate from MediaPlaybackSession in MediaPlayerElement and it indeed became 1.0 when playing another video. I searched the UWP document about this but UWP does not have such API that can keep PlaybackRate throughout the lifetime of the MediaPlayerElement like DefaultPlaybackRate. So currently, you can only set the PlaybackRate manually when you play avideo every time.

Comment: Is there any way to report this issue to MS dev team? Thx.

Comment: If you want to get this feature, you can go to Feedback Hub(Start menu-> Feedback Hub) to submit your feature request.

Comment: I submited many issues before, but none of them solved.

Comment: The feature request needs upvote. The more votes you have, the easier it is for the team to notice.